# Padded text padding overflow not affecting word break

Tags: html, css, text, background

Word "under" should go to next line, but it doesn't cause of inline padding i think.

Is there anyway i can get text to break to next line when white padding touches edge of container.

**Text needs to stay as inline cause i need that blank space between text lines.** Tho if you have solution which requires to change that and result looks same as mine only the problem is fixed, than that will work too.

P.S. My container in real situation is 100% 100% so width,height is not fixed for the block.

It seems like it's not possible cause inline padding doesnt affect wrapping in any way and is completely ignored.

```css
body {
  background: #111111;
}
.container {
  width: 338px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 95px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
.sub {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  line-height: 90px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Heading title</h1>
  <br/>
  <span class="sub">Some random text under heading title</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want it to look? Because "under heading title" is on the next line with a different block.

Comment: I want it to look same way as my example is, but when padding goes over container edge, word needs jump to next line.

Comment: I'm sorry for everyone if i did not explain my problem in a way you can understand, but i have very hard time explaining this.

Comment: This is kinda hacky... but does adding a wrapping div with left and right padding help your situation? See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guy682ow/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @zgood but i tried this already. wraper and container still completely ignores inline padding. https://jsfiddle.net/guy682ow/1/ when i increase padding in your example you can see everything goes horribly wrong, and the inline text is off center.

Comment: Funny thing is that left padding works as it is supposed to but overflow on right side goes as far as left+right padding sum, thats realy strange.

Comment: @Enkss I think with `inline` elements it just looks at the content to determine if it needs to wrap, it doesn't calculate padding + content. It probably just calculates the content and determines if it fits and wraps where necessary, then adds the left and right padding **after** that even if it overflows. The best you could do probably is `overflow: hidden;` on your wrapping container, but then yes the padding would look inconsistent on the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was very simple. Just had to remove side padding from my inline elements, add instead of it add box shadow like this

```
box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #fff, -20px 0 0 #fff;
```

For 20px on each side. (same as padding size i used before)
And now white bg behind inline elements looks like overflows on each side of the container(but actually its just the box shadow). So adding same padding as the size for box shadow on each side of the container makes it perfect.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jy2w9p0v/)

```css
body {
  background: #111111;
}
.container {
  width: 298px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 95px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #fff, -20px 0 0 #fff;
}
.sub {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  line-height: 90px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #fff, -20px 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Heading title</h1>
  <br/>
  <span class="sub">Some random text under heading title</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `inline-block` rather than `inline` you get the desired behaviour but this will cause both lines to be wrapped in one box element.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/po80paLn/1/) with the changed style, all I changed was:

```
.sub {
  display: inline-block; // was "inline"
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  line-height: 90px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

***More details on the problem you are facing:***

In your given example, the width of your `h1` is determined by the widest element on your page which is the `container`. So as soon as the width of the heading exceeds the width of the wrapping element, it wraps to the next line. Your rule `box-decoration-break: clone;` is not used to somehow cut the heading into two same-width elements, it simply makes sure that the padding on both wrapped elements is the same, if you had omitted it, you would not get a padding on the right of the first and no padding on the left of the second line.

---

## Another idea

You could use a trick to get your desired result that does not involve any JS:

As the wrapping position of the title is defined by the next element defining the width, you can add your title in a `DIV` with a defined width. This will then make sure that the title wraps at the right position as you can see in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/4xfpwxg2/). Basically that's the code you need:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="defined-width-for-heading">
  <span class="sub">Some random text under heading title</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.defined-width-for-heading {
  width: 300px;
}

.sub {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  line-height: 90px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Comment: It has to be inline, cause i need text to have background color and space between lines, changing to inline-block makes text next line background same width as the widest one and that won't work for me.

Comment: @Enkss I added another approach to my question to get your desired effect. Have a look if this helps.

Comment: Your second method doesn't seem to change anything still cause padding can overflow it's all off center.

Answer (score 0):

```
.sub {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Change the display to block/inline-block and remove line-height. I hope it would help.

Comment: Changing display type won't work for me. It needs to look same way as my example, just so text jumps to next line when padding overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Without using JS you won't be able to get the needed result just by CSS.
Your current code allows `<span>` to overflow container's border (not sure why) while `<h1>` tag breaks the word exactly on containers box border. My best guess is to include whole text in `<h1>` and use class definition for `<h1>` and with `<span>` as a child element to change the `line-height` & general styling of elements below.

I'd suggest to redo your code like an example below.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span { 
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}

h1.title span{
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff; 
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

h1.desc span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <h1 class="title">
    <span>Long heading title here</span>
  </h1>
  
  <h1 class="desc">
    <span>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</span>
  </h1>
</section>
```

As you can see in snippet both `<span>` & `<h1>` elements respect the `.container` border and doesn't overflow it.